# Chrome Colspan not working after update

Tags: css, google-chrome

Just updated Chrome and now I am getting this issue with colspan and my tables.  Works fine in Firefox and IE still.  Adding extra colspan.  Is this something others have seen and if so where should I report it?

[image]

Comment: Where's your [mcve] and what exactly is "this issue"?

Comment: It's really hard to paste the code for this project as there is a ton.  This is more of, is Chrome having an issue with HTML rendering and if so do we know what it is?  Screenshot shows the issue quite clearly.

Comment: highly doubtful, try it with a simple <table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
</table> works just fine, there's a problem in your html/jscript.

Comment: Just updated Chrome, works fine in Firefox and IE, nothing has changed on my end.  This has happened before with Chrome.

Comment: Upgrade to Firefox is more stable ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was an issue in Chromium.  I guess a different version of Chrome which I didn't know I had.